# Moving video on every slide in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm just poking around in VBA with PowerPoint and know that what I want to do can be done. I just don't know the write calls/sytanx to use!

I want a macro that will run through all the slides in a presentation and move the video object to specific spot on the slide. The spot will be the same on all slides.

It would be very helpful if someone could show me how to do this!  Or at least point me in the right direction.   Thanks!

Here's what I found for doing something on every slide

```
Sub EveryTextBoxOnSlide()
' Performs some operation on every shape that contains text on every slide
' (doesn't affect charts, tables, etc)

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' If font size is mixed, don't touch the font size
                    If .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size > 0 Then
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size + 2
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next    ' shape
Next    ' slide

NormalExit:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Resume Next

End Sub
```

And this is something I found to move the object to desired location (here's where I don't know what to call the video object)

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
.Left = 640 'change the number for desired x position
.Top = 75 'change the number for desired y position
End With
End Sub
Sub ll()

End Sub
```

So basically, I want to run the last piece as a function of the first one instead of shapes with text.    Does that make sense?

I've done some programming in the past, mainly with actionscript and Flash. I could probably write out some basic functions, just not sure how to run it in VBA without learning a whole new language. Which I don't want to do, since I'm an instructional designer and don't have the free time to learn it!  :)

Comment: Fire up the macro recorder in PowerPoint and... Oh, MS took it out of PowerPoint because they hate every single one of us... :/

Comment: In all seriousness, search here for code to loop through the slides in your PPT - it's a simple loop structure. Then loop through all the shapes on your slide to identify the video, then set the `.Top` and `.Left` properties of the video shape to the desired location.

Comment: I found code to do loop through slides.  I was having a hard time to identify the video, though. I found examples of objects or text, but don't know how to name video!

Comment: Post what code you've come up with and where the specific problem is that you've run into. Maybe leave in all the commented code of things you've tried and why they didn't work for you. With code & a specific question you're [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help) otherwise, this may get closed as OT, or just ignored...

Comment: @FreeMan I updated it. Hope it make sense

Comment: Please roll-back your edit to show the original code. That's the custom here. Otherwise, a future _James_ who comes along looking for help with a very similar/identical problem won't know what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function that'll return True if the shape you pass to it is a video, and a bit of example code to test it with:

```
Function IsVideo(oSh As Shape) As Boolean

    If oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
        If oSh.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
            IsVideo = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' Things get a little trickier if the movie is in a placeholder
    ' Is it a placeholder? and is it a media object?
    If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoMedia Then
            ' it's a media object, but we don't know if it's
            ' a movie or sound or what, so we duplicate it
            ' then look at the duplicate (which is now a copy
            ' of the placeholder content but is not a placeholder itself)
            With oSh.Duplicate
                If .Type = msoMedia Then
                    If .MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                        IsVideo = True
                    End If
                End If
                ' and delete the duplicate
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Function

Sub thing()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If IsVideo(oSh) Then
                oSh.Left = 0
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!

The object is a video recorded using the Office Mix add-in.  Mix will put the video on the top right corner of the slide, but with the template I'm designing, it needs to be in a different location (plus, it kinda looks bad in that spot!). 

I do understand a little bit of programming, so I can follow along. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Ok, I modified it  to include moving audio objects off of the slide.

However, audio recorded in Office Mix is treated like a movie object!  I recorded audio using the insert function, and the code worked. 

Do you know how to differentiate between the audio and video generated by Mix?

Comment: So what I did was create a separate function that checked the size of the object after it was determined to be a Movie. If it was under 50, it would make the boolean IsAudio active, and then added a new line that moved IsAudio true objects to a different location. And it worked!

Comment: Nicely done.  I don't use Mix so haven't had any run-ins with what it adds to PPT.

Answer (score 0):

Now you're getting somewhere!

I don't know what kind of shape holds your video, so this modification should help you identify it.

```
Sub EveryTextBoxOnSlide()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
          .Select
        End With
    Next
Next

NormalExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  Resume Next

End Sub
```

While there is no need whatsoever to use the `.Select` in your final code, this is only here to help you identify *which* shape actually holds the video. Put a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) on that line and run your code (<kbd>F5</kbd>), then debug through it with <kbd>F8</kbd> to execute one line at a time and run through your loop looking at each shape until you see that your video has been selected.

Once your video has been selected look at the various properties (using the `Immediate Window` of the IDE) of `oSh` until you find the uniqueness that identifies this is your video. (There may be some property about the content type of the shape, or a link on where to find the contents that contains the text string ".avi", ".mpg", ".flv", etc - there will be *some* sort of identifier you can find.)

Once you've identified what makes the shape the holder of a video, replace

```
.Select
```

with

```
If {my video containing shape criteria is true} Then 
  With .Selection.ShapeRange
    .Left = 640 'change the number for desired x position
    .Top = 75 'change the number for desired y position
  End With
End If
```

Changing the values (as commented) to whatever it is that you need.

**Important Note:** It is very good that your sample code has some error handling built in, but all this error handler is doing is sweeping any errors under the rug. This particular handler is the very long form version of `On Error Resume Next` which does have its uses, but in very, very limited situations.

As you get your code working, you'll actually want to put something useful in the `ErrorHandler:` section, but that's the topic for a whole new question.

Comment: Ok, we're getting there!  I have the video selected, but not sure how to check the properties. I have Immediate Window open in the editor, but not sure if that's what you mean!

Comment: in the Immediate Window, type `?oSh.` and IntelliSense will pop up the list of all available properties and methods. Scroll through the properties looking for something that will help you identify what kind of shape it is. Unfortunately, I can't help you there because it's been forever since I embedded a video in a PPT, and I certainly wasn't modifying it with VBA at the time. When you find a likely looking candidate, select it & hit `Enter`, you'll get the value of that property printed out.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I have a bit of a headache now, so I'll tackle this again tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how I modified the code supplied above to do this in my case:

```
 Sub EveryTextBoxOnSlide() ' Performs some operation on every shape that contains text on every slide ' (doesn't affect charts, tables, etc) Dim oSh As Shape Dim oSl As Slide On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
           If .Type = msoMedia Then
                 If .MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 236
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 314.2115
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 8.737323
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = 0
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeHeight = 236.3478
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeWidth = 163
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeLeft = 796.6956
                    .PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeTop = 0
                 End If
           End If
        End With
    Next    ' shape Next    ' slide

NormalExit: Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: Resume Next

End Sub
```